# excel - software function instead of excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

Excel has functions and VBA.

I would like to have one formula and call it on each row but not have the formula replicated on each row for the cell value.

Is this possible through formula or only through VBA?

ex.

formula calC (Value1, Value2)
Value3 =Value1+Value2
return Value3

CellA1 = call calC(1+1) = A1 = 2
CellA2 = call calC(1+2) = A2 = 3

Comment: Like a macro that loops through a bunch of rows and does something to them?

Comment: That depends on which version of excel you have.

Comment: Can you elaborate with more details on what you're exactly trying to do and what the data is like and what the end result is. If it's easier, share the formula you're trying to do for the rows.

Answer (score 1):

With the dynamic array formula introduced in Office 365 Excel you can spill the results.  for example put:

```
=1+SEQUENCE(10)
```

In A1 and the results will spill down automatically.

[image]

If one does not have dynamic array formula then one will need to array enter the a formula, so highlight ten rows and in the formula bar put:

```
=1+ROW(1:10)
```

Then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array enter the formula.

[image]

But this will put the formula as an array in each cell.

Outside of that, one will need a subroutine in vba that is called in someway.  A UDF(User Defined Function) will have the same limitations as the formulas described above.